# Testing with runSaga with take and delay

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-saga

If I have a saga with this form:

```
function * sagaWorker() {
  yield put(START_ACTION)
  yield take(WAIT_FOR_ACTION)
  yield delay(100)
  yield put(END_ACTION)
}
```

I can successfully test it using `runSaga` like this:

```
step('saga passes the tests', async () => {
  const channel = stdChannel()
  const dispatched = []
  const options = {
    dispatch: action => dispatched.push(action),
    getState: () => {},
    channel
  }
  const task = runSaga(options, sagaWorker)
  channel.put(WAIT_FOR_ACTION)
  await task.toPromise()
  expect(dispatched).to.deep.eql([START_ACTION, END_ACTION])
})
```

However, if I move the delay in front of the take:

```
function * sagaWorker() {
  yield put(START_ACTION)
  yield delay(100)
  yield take(WAIT_FOR_ACTION)
  yield put(END_ACTION)
}
```

Now the saga doesn't run to completion and times out - it gets to the `take` but the action never arrives in the channel.

Is it possible to test it using this form? I suspect I can make it work by `call`ing the `delay`s rather than `yield`ing them directly but I'd like to know how to make it work without doing that (if it's possible).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `yield call(() => myPromiseyDelay(500))` won't save you here. There will still be nothing to notice the "lost" action at the time it's dispatched.

When you post your `WAIT_FOR_ACTION` the saga is is in a yielded state on the `yield delay`. There is no queue for actions here, so by the time you get to `yield take(WAIT_FOR_ACTION)`, the `WAIT_FOR_ACTION` action has long since been dispatched, unnoticed by any of the saga logic you presented above (there was no active `take` to grab the action).

Consider setting up an [`actionChannel`](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/blob/master/docs/advanced/Channels.md#using-the-actionchannel-effect) to capture these unlistened-for actions. They'll be queued up in the channel, ready-to-consume, after the `delay` has completed.

So, something like:

```
function * sagaWorker() {
  const channel = yield actionChannel(WAIT_FOR_ACTION)
  yield put(START_ACTION)
  yield delay(100)
  yield take(channel)
  yield put(END_ACTION)
}
```

So putting this all together as non-pseudocode:

```js
const {
  runSaga,
  stdChannel,
  effects: {
    take,
    put,
    actionChannel,
    delay
  }
} = window.ReduxSaga

const WAIT_FOR_ACTION = "WAIT_FOR_ACTION";
const START_ACTION = "START_ACTION";
const END_ACTION = "END_ACTION";

(async() => {
  const channel = stdChannel();
  const dispatched = [];
  const options = {
    dispatch: action => dispatched.push(action),
    getState: () => {},
    channel
  };
  const task = runSaga(options, sagaWorker);
  channel.put({
    type: WAIT_FOR_ACTION
  });
  await task.toPromise();
  console.log(dispatched);
})();

function* sagaWorker() {
  const channel = yield actionChannel(WAIT_FOR_ACTION);
  yield put({
    type: START_ACTION
  });
  yield delay(100);
  yield take(channel);
  yield put({
    type: END_ACTION
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/redux-saga@1.1.3/dist/redux-saga.umd.min.js"></script>
```